# Connecting to Cassandra on startup, and monitoring session health

Tags: phantom-dsl

Two related questions

1) Currently, the session to C* is established in  a lazy fashion - aka, only on the first any table is accessed.
Instead, we would like to establish a session as soon as the application is started (in case there is a connectivity problem, etc. ). What would be the best way to do that? Should I just get a session object in my startup code?

```
connector.provider.session
```

2) How would I then monitor the health of the connection?  I could call

```
connector.provider.session.isClosed()
```

but I'm not sure it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't manually rely on that mechanism per say as you may want to get more metrics out of the cluster, for which purpose you have native JMX support, so through the JMX protocol you can look at metrics in more detail.

Now obviously you have OpsCenter which natively leverages this feature, but alternatively you can use a combination of a JMX listener with something like Graphana(just a thought) or whatever supports native compatibility.

In terms of low level methods, yes, you are on the money:

`connector.provider.session.isClosed()`

But you also have heartbeats that you can log and look at and so on. There's more detail [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/index.html?com/datastax/driver/core/Metrics.html).

Comment: Thanks! We are also doing JMX monitoring, but want to add a simple C* check to an service 'health' api end point that will be exposed to other services. What happens when a connection to C* get's lost? is a session closed and then restarted? Can a session be open while the network to C* is down?

Comment: @EugeneMi No, not as far as I know. It could be open if multiple nodes are connected under the same session, and some of the nodes are down but others up.